# transfer file from one subfolder of one repository to another in bitbucket without loosing history

Tags: github, bitbucket, git-bash

I recently discovered that as part of my project, a file was placed in the wrong location and now I need to move it to the appropriate directory in the correct repository. My issue is that I wish to retain the commit history.

I have been following a GitHub Community thread titled "[Adding a folder from one repo to another](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Adding-a-folder-from-one-repo-to-another/td-p/5425)" via Git Bash but this deals with the entire sub-directory and not just one file.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to the new place where it is needed to be, after that make a commit

Git will automatically maintain history even if the commit is for changing file path or adding comment line in the code.